# Solr 8.8 - trouble matching partial words with eDisMax and EdgeNGramFilter

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr and trying to provide partial word matching with Solr 8.8.1, but partials are giving no results. I have combed the blogs without luck to fix this.

For example, the text of the document contains the word `longer`. Index analysis gives `lon`, `long`, `longe`, `longer`. If I query `longer` using `alltext_en:longer`, I get a match. However, if I query (for example) `longe` using `alltext_en:longe`, I get no match. explainOther returns `0.0 = No matching clauses`.

It seems that I am missing something obvious, since this is not a complex phrase query.

Apologies in advance if I have missed any needed details - I will update the question if you tell me what else is needed to know.

Here are the relevant field specs from my managed-schema:

```
  <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="15" minGramSize="3"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>

  <dynamicField name="*_txt_en" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="alltext_en" type="text_en" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <copyField source="*_txt_en" dest="alltext_en"/>
```

Here is the relevant part of solrconfig.xml:

```
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

       <!-- Query settings -->
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="q">*:*</str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">50</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score,[explain]</str>
       <str name="ps">10</str>

       <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
       <str name="hl">on</str>
       <str name="hl.fl">_text_</str>
       <str name="hl.preserveMulti">true</str>
       <str name="hl.encoder">html</str>
       <str name="hl.simple.pre">&lt;span class="artica-snippet"&gt;</str>
       <str name="hl.simple.post">&lt;/span&gt;</str>

       <!-- Spell checking defaults -->
       <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">2</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">3</str>
     </lst>

     <arr name="last-components">
       <str>spellcheck</str>
     </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: That stemming filter will modify the tokens in ways you don't predict - and since they only happen on the token you try to match agains the ngrammed tokens when querying, the token might not be what you expect). If you're generating ngrams, stemming filters should usually be removed. I'd also remove the possessive filter (Also, small note - try to avoid using `*` when formatting text, since it's hard to know if you've used it when querying and the formatting is an error - instead use a backtick to indicate that the text is a code keyword/query.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That stemming filter will modify the tokens in ways you don't predict - and since they only happen on the token you try to match agains the ngrammed tokens when querying, the token might not be what you expect). If you're generating ngrams, stemming filters should usually be removed. I'd also remove the possessive filter (Also, small note - try to avoid using * when formatting text, since it's hard to know if you've used it when querying and the formatting is an error - instead use a backtick to indicate that the text is a code keyword/query.) – MatsLindh

That answered it - I removed the stemmer from the index step and everything was fine. Brilliant, thank you, @MatsLindh!